# How to build query if request not null?

Tags: laravel, search, input, filter

I have 3 inputs (id,city,amount) for filter, and table with results. 
If I don't have any request I need query `Model::all()->paginate(10)`.

If `$request->id` not null I need query Model::where('id', $request->id)->paginate(10).

If `$request->id and $request->city and $request->amount` not null I need query

```
Model::where(['id' => $request->id, 'city' => $request->city...])->paginate(10)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1. check each request variable with `$hasId = $request->has('id') && ! empty($request->id)` one by one
2. Have multiple `where` statements base on the result shown above , for example:

```php
$model = New Model();
if ($hasId) {
 $model->where('id', $id);
}
...
```

Eloquent uses Fluent, so you don't have to assign them back, just keep attaching where statements to it like there is no tomorrow.

3. profit